# Trouble with Feeds Import CSV on Localhost

Tags: feeds

I'm using feeds node importer to import a csv file on my disk. It seems like no matter what I do, select the file from file system or put in the path for the file. I always get Error Message "Resource is not a file or it is an empty directory".

my localhost is at /var/www
Drupal 7 Folder: /var/www/drupal7
I stored the file at /var/www/drupal7/sites/default/files/feeds/bsif.csv
so I put the file path as public://drupal7/sites/default/files/feeds/bsif.csv
but it's not working

Comment: I'm thinking it should be public://feeds/bsif.csv

Comment: IT WORKS. Thanks alot. But I still don't get why I can't select from file system. Is it because the site is on localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In the case where you manually upload the file and then map to it, try public://feeds/bsif.csv
- In the case where you try to upload using your browser, it should be working fine.  It could be that you're unable to upload files in general, not just with the feeds import module.
  **Check your server's access to upload to /sites/default/files**... it could be that only your account has access to place the file there.  Also, Apache/PHP uses a tmp directory for file uploads, so it will need access there as well.